# Only first letter extracted from Json

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I suddenly get a really weird problem with my iOS app.
I use to receive Jsons from a server and I extract some information from them. Everything is working perfectly, except for one user account : I only get the first character of the attributes.

For example, if the Json is like that :

```
{
    name : "Joey"
}
```

And I extract the name attribute, I get the string "J".
I have to precise that it works perfectly with all other user accounts.

I'm thinking about an encoding problem ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

EDIT :

Here is how I get the server's response :

```
+ (void)getDataFromServ:(NSString *)urlServ withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSDictionary *dataDic))completion {

   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlServ]];
   [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

   NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
   NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler: ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
       if (error) {
           return;
       }

       NSDictionary *serDataDic = nil;
       NSError* parseError;
       if (data) {

           serDataDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
           completion(serDataDic);
       }
   }];

   [task resume];
}
```

And here is how I process the response :

```
...

[self getDataFromServ:urlServ withCompletionHandler:^(NSDictionary *dataDic) {

        NSDictionary *response = [dataDic objectForKey:@"data"];

        NSLog(@"Response : %@", response);
        NSLog (@"Name : %@", [response objectForKey:@"name"]);

...
}
```

Here are the related logs :

```
Response : 
{
    name = "Joey";
}

Name : J
```

EDIT 2 :

An other thing I just noticed, when I extract an attribute and calculate its length, the length is longer than the attribute.
For example, when I have a attribute with 15 characters, the calculated length is 29 but the attribute still appears with only one character.

EDIT 3 :

I tested something else :

```
for (NSInteger j = 0; j < displayNameStr.length; j++) {

                            NSLog(@"displayname : %@, j : %d", [nameExtracted substringFromIndex:j], j);                        
}


2015-04-07 11:25:34.778 myApp[434:131660] displayname : A
2015-04-07 11:25:34.778 myApp[434:131660] displayname :
2015-04-07 11:25:34.779 myApp[434:131660] displayname : l
2015-04-07 11:25:34.779 myApp[434:131660] displayname :
2015-04-07 11:25:34.779 myApp[434:131660] displayname : l
2015-04-07 11:25:34.780 myApp[434:131660] displayname :
2015-04-07 11:25:34.780 myApp[434:131660] displayname : a
2015-04-07 11:25:34.781 myApp[434:131660] displayname :
2015-04-07 11:25:34.781 myApp[434:131660] displayname : i
2015-04-07 11:25:34.781 myApp[434:131660] displayname :
2015-04-07 11:25:34.782 myApp[434:131660] displayname : n
2015-04-07 11:25:34.782 myApp[434:131660] displayname :
2015-04-07 11:25:34.783 myApp[434:131660] displayname : o
2015-04-07 11:25:34.784 myApp[434:131660] displayname :
2015-04-07 11:25:34.784 myApp[434:131660] displayname : u
2015-04-07 11:25:34.788 myApp[434:131660] displayname :
2015-04-07 11:25:34.788 myApp[434:131660] displayname :  D
2015-04-07 11:25:34.789 myApp[434:131660] displayname : D
2015-04-07 11:25:34.789 myApp[434:131660] displayname :
2015-04-07 11:25:34.789 myApp[434:131660] displayname : u
2015-04-07 11:25:34.790 myApp[434:131660] displayname :
2015-04-07 11:25:34.790 myApp[434:131660] displayname : p
2015-04-07 11:25:34.790 myApp[434:131660] displayname :
2015-04-07 11:25:34.791 myApp[434:131660] displayname : r
2015-04-07 11:25:34.791 myApp[434:131660] displayname :
2015-04-07 11:25:34.792 myApp[434:131660] displayname : a
2015-04-07 11:25:34.792 myApp[434:131660] displayname :
2015-04-07 11:25:34.792 myApp[434:131660] displayname : -
2015-04-07 11:25:34.793 myApp[434:131660] displayname :
2015-04-07 11:25:34.793 myApp[434:131660] displayname : B
2015-04-07 11:25:34.794 myApp[434:131660] displayname :
2015-04-07 11:25:34.794 myApp[434:131660] displayname : e
2015-04-07 11:25:34.794 myApp[434:131660] displayname :
2015-04-07 11:25:34.795 myApp[434:131660] displayname : l
2015-04-07 11:25:34.795 myApp[434:131660] displayname :
2015-04-07 11:25:34.795 myApp[434:131660] displayname : l
2015-04-07 11:25:34.796 myApp[434:131660] displayname :
2015-04-07 11:25:34.796 myApp[434:131660] displayname : a
2015-04-07 11:25:34.798 myApp[434:131660] displayname :
2015-04-07 11:25:34.798 myApp[434:131660] displayname : n
2015-04-07 11:25:34.798 myApp[434:131660] displayname :
```

The name's attribute was : Allainou Dupra-bellan

Comment: Can you show some code, please? How do you initialise the string?

Comment: It is impossible for us to suggest a solution if you do not include some _real_ code/data in your question

Comment: Either Joey was encoded differently, or some treatment happens about that specific user that has "somethign" different. But we can't really help unless you show us how it looks like from start to end.
:)

Comment: Try to execute the block code in the main thread: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    });

Comment: isn't this just an encoding problem like UTC8 and UTC16 ? are there any BOM (Byte Order Marks) in the front of the text?

Comment: Is the Web API you calling an Open one so we can test it?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks a lot for all your answers.
Nothing worked unfortunately, and the API I'm calling is not an open one.

I contacted my server's admin, I'll post something if I find a solution..

Answer (score 0):

Code needed. [Got code! Thanks]

But, things you can do:

- Try to put a breakpoint on the line it happens, and inspect the variable to see if everything is there.
- How are you decoding the JSON? Try to see if your are not getting the strings in a way you were not supposed to.
- Use a HTTP(S) proxy app to take a look at the data that is coming from the server (Fiddler, Charles Proxy, Wireshark).

**Edit:** 
Everything seems to be fine... weird result. But, as not following the specification may lead to weird results, try:

Replace:

```
serDataDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
```

With:

```
serDataDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&parseError];
```

I don't think it's the source of the problem, but it's worth giving it a try.

Also, can you please give us the entire JSON string that you get from the server? I tested it locally just with the JSON you gave and I got "Joey" properly.

**Edit 2:**
After your weird length result, I would definitely check the response from the server. The problem doesn't seem to be on your Objective-C code.

Comment: That's more comment material than answer material Gustavo :)

Comment: I tried your first advice and it didn't work, I'll just talk to my serv admin :). Thanks for your answers !

Comment: Don't write this line:                                                                             NSDictionary *response = [dataDic objectForKey:@"data"];

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `stringValue` at the end of your `[response objectForKey:@"name"]`:

`[[response objectForKey:@"name"] stringValue]`